# Proving an equation for inverse functions

Tags: analysis

We have $f: X \to Y$ function, and $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ is an indexed family, where for all $i\in I$ indexes, $E_i\subseteq Y$.
How do I show that $f^{-1}(\cup_{i\in I}E_i)=\cup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(E_i)$

(where $f^{-1}$ means the inverse function of $f$; I don't know if this is the correct way to write that)

Comment: Do you mean inverse image? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image

Comment: I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function

Answer (score 1):

In one direction, $x\in f^{-1}(\cup_{i\in I} E_i)$ implies $\exists j\in I$ such that $f(x)\in E_j$. This means $x\in f^{-1}(E_j)\subset\cup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(E_i)$.

Conversely, $x\in \cup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(E_i)$ means $\exists j\in I$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(E_j)$, which in turn implies that $f(x)\in E_j\subset\cup_{i\in I}E_i$. This gives $x\in f^{-1}(\cup_{i\in I}E_i)$.